# PostgreSQL Parameter error (timestamp with time zone, timestamp without time zone)

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I get an error

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function months_between(timestamp with time zone, timestamp without time zone) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 310
```

I already found the cause of this error is because the parameter didn't match to => (timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone)

```
TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (date_trunc('day', now()), people.original_date_of_hire) / 12) masa_bekerja_year, ");
```

So, how to match this syntax parameter with this right param => (timestamp without timezone, timestamp without timezone)? I need to match to this, because my framework using this parameter format and I'm not allowed to change the framework.

Comment: There is no MONTHS_BETWEEN function in postgres [Doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: its custom function that we created in postgre schema function as a framework, as i said i want to match the parameter with it

Answer (score 0):

To force a `CAST`:

```
TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (date_trunc('day', now())::timestamp, people.original_date_of_hire::timestamp) / 12) masa_bekerja_year, ");
```

Be aware that there are potential time zone conversions that take place when you do this. For more details see the section below:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES

> 8.5.1.3. Time Stamps